# Beeline Session Getting Reset

Tags: hive, beeline

I have a hiveserver2 installation where below timeout configs are set:

> hive.server2.session.check.interval=3600000
>   hive.server2.idle.operation.timeout=7200000
>   hive.server2.idle.session.timeout=86400000

However, if I open a connection from a remote server with beeline (and leave it idle), the connection gets reset after about 10 minutes with below message.

> Error: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException:
>   java.net.SocketException: Connection reset (state=08S01,code=0)

Has anyone faced this issue before? If so, please let me know.

Thanks